# php adding value to session

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to implement a 'shopping cart' where, if the 'Add to Cart' has been clicked, the respective item is either added to the cart or incremented by one if already present. However, the following code isn't working and giving me a "Cannot use a scalar value as an array" error. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
if (isset($_POST['fan']) && ($_POST['fan']=="Add to Cart")) {
    if (($_SESSION['cart']['fan']==0) || (!isset($_SESSION['cart']['fan']))) {
      $_SESSION['cart']['fan']=1;
    } else {
      $_SESSION['cart']['fan']++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted won't produce the scalar error. Even with your undefined `cart` element, it will only produce an `undefined index` notice. You must have some other code that is causing the error. Find out which line it is and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suppose you may have forgot to add something like this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{
  $_SESSION['cart']=array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `$_SESSION['cart']` as `array()` if it is not set,

```
$_SESSION['cart']=array();
```